# How can I get notepad++ highlighting working for powershell using the Twilight theme?

Tags: powershell, notepad++, colors, themes, xml

So I got started by manually importing the powershell lexertype from stylers.xml to twilight.xml.  I knew to do that much.  However after going through and matching the coloring as close as i could to the powershell ISE I was left with a few blank spots.  As evidenced by my screenshot, some cmdlet's such as `Write-Host` are highlighted properly, however others such as `Enable-ScheduledTask` are devoid of any coloring/highlighting.

Items such as `-TaskName` and `-TaskPath` (i have no idea what these are called?) are apparently not defined in the stylers and as such not defined in the twilight.xml theme which leaves them uncolored/un-highlighted.

I'm looking to get the last few items properly identified and colored within the theme.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use notepad++ to code PowerShell in the first place? The PowerShell ISE is the most powerful tool to script PowerShell, as it hat Auto completion and all the other useful features?

Comment: call it habit, familiarity etc.  I'm brand new to powershell anyways, not going to be doing any heavy lifting. 

I believe I found the answer im looking for though.

Comment: If you wanr to use npp, then you might want to have a look at this project: https://github.com/Cmohan/NPPPowershell It has other features like auto completion as well.

Comment: If u don't mind, pls share the found/applied solution for the formatting (I have similar issue with phyton).

Answer (score 1):

using `get-command` in powershell will provide a complete list of powershell commands including the un-highlighted ones in my original question.

they need to be entered into the langs.xml file in order to respect the coloring indicated in your chosen theme.

the other option is you can create a user defined language from scratch but for someone unfamiliar with the language that would be substantially more taxing.

Comment: you will need to update that file whenever you add new modules. I'd bite the bullet and do everything in PowerShell_ISE. way less head ache. and if you find yourself writing more and more PS, I'd switch to Visual Studio Code.